# Adding FILTER to AVERAGEX function gives error Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

**I have below measure:**

```
AVG Closed Claims =
AVERAGEX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        fact_Loss,
        fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY],
        "Average", COUNT ( fact_Loss[ClaimID] )
    ),
    [Average]
)
```

I simply need to add filter statement to eliminate values when`ClosedMMYY` is `blank`

**So I am trying something like this:**

```
AVG Closed Claims =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGEX (
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER ( fact_Loss, fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY] <> BLANK () ),
            fact_Loss,
            fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY],
            "Average", COUNT ( fact_Loss[ClaimID] )
        ),
        [Average]
    )
)
```

But it gives me an error.

Where should I place this `FILTER`?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

You've got two tables in the `SUMMARIZE` now. Just used the filtered one.

```
AVG Closed Claims =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGEX (
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER ( fact_Loss, fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY] <> BLANK () ),
            -- Remove this one => fact_Loss,
            fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY],
            "Average", COUNT ( fact_Loss[ClaimID] )
        ),
        [Average]
    )
)
```

In the above, you don't need the `CALCULATE`. If you're using `CALCULATE`, then write it like this:

```
AVG Closed Claims =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGEX (
        SUMMARIZE (
            fact_Loss,
            fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY],
            "Average", COUNT ( fact_Loss[ClaimID] )
        ),
        [Average]
    ),
    fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY] <> BLANK ()
)
```

Otherwise this:

```
AVG Closed Claims =
AVERAGEX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( fact_Loss, fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY] <> BLANK () ),
        fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY],
        "Average", COUNT ( fact_Loss[ClaimID] )
    ),
    [Average]
)
```

Note that these are not exactly equivalent since a `CALCULATE` boolean filter *replaces* that columns filter context rather than just adding another condition.

Comment: Oh!  Thank you !